# How to show the following inequality: $|x^p - y^p| \leq |x - y| \cdot p \cdot (|x| + |x - y|)^{p - 1}$ ($1 \leq p < \infty$)

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I would like to show the following inequality for all $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $x, y \geq 0$:

$|x^p - y^p| \leq |x - y| \cdot p \cdot (|x| + |x - y|)^{p - 1}$

For $p = n \in \mathbb{N}$, this is easy to show, since we then have:

$|x^n - y^n| = \left| (x - y) \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} x^k y^{(n - 1) - k} \right| \leq |x - y| \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} |x|^k |y|^{(n - 1) - k} \leq |x - y| \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (|x| + |x - y|)^k (|x| + |x - y|)^{(n - 1) - k} = |x - y| \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (|x| + |x - y|)^{n - 1} = |x - y| \cdot n \cdot (|x| + |x - y|)^{n - 1}$

However, I don't know how to show this inequality for general $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Mean Value Theorem $|x^{p}-y^{p}|=|x-y|(pt^{p-1})$ for some $t$ between $x$ and $y$. Suppose $x \le y$. Then $x \le t\le y$ and $t^{p-1}\le y^{p-1} \le (|x|+|x-y|)^{p-1}$. The case $y<x$ is simpler.